# Creating new files based on pattern matching with regex, sprintf() and fopen()

Tags: c, regex, fopen

I have a large text file containing only function definitions in a pseudo programming language. A function definition looks like this (They can be as complex as they want though (deep bracketing etc.).):

```
foo1 = FUNCTION() {

    body
}
```

I use a `C`-program with `regex.h` and grouped pattern matching. `fgets()` reads in new lines in a `while`-loop until the end of the file. Every time `regexec()` matches  `foo1 = FUNCTION` in a line `fgets()` read in I calculate `foo1` from `regmatch_t`, pass it to `sprintf()` and open a new file with `fopen(foo1, "wx")`. All the following lines will then be written into the newly opened file until `regexec()` matches a new `foon = FUNCTION() {}` and a new file is opened via `sprintf()` and `fopen()`. This is the part of the solution I would like to keep!

But the author of the file was sloppy in some parts and instead of putting the name of the function and it's definition-keyword `FUNCTION` on the same line, he sometimes wrote:

```
foo2 = 
FUNCTION() {
    body
}
```

Currently I treat such functions as unnamed and assign the file they get written into a name of the form `m_func` where `n` is a running index. Now, the file previous to `m_func` (`m-1_func`) will also contain as the last line the actual name of `m_func`. Given that `m = 50` at least, copying and pasting seems a nuisance. So here is the question: Is there a way to achieve the same I achieved with functions defined on one line such that I can match the definition, then somehow get hold of the name one or two lines before and create a new file based upon the name of the function via `fopen()` and `sprintf()`?

Comment: You could pre-process the file and create a new one, analysing each line to see it is complete.

Comment: Can't you switch to single line mode in the regular expressions? What you want to do (backtracking) seems more complicated. [See this site](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/regular-expression-matches-multiple-line-example-java/)

Comment: You need to define the grammar of that pseudo programming language and write a parser. Have a look at flex and bison

Comment: and there goes my intention of keeping it easy...